# I have an auto scroll problem with PDFVIEW

Tags: android-studio, androidpdfviewer

**> Autoscroll works but does not load the second page of the pdf it shows blank I want to bind the scrollHandle to the motion and speed of the seekbar which auto scrolls the screen down:**

**This is a pdf library:**

```
    public void Show_Full_Text() {
        Title_Text = globalVar.getMain_Title();      
        this.setTitle(Title_Text);
        pdfView.fromAsset("pdf/page_" + page_id + ".pdf")
                
                .onRender(new OnRenderListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onInitiallyRendered
                            (int nbPages, float pageWidth, float pageHeight)
                    {
                        pdfView.fitToWidth();
                    }
                })
           .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
                .load();

    }
```

**This is seekbar code that auto-animates:**

```
seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekbartt);
        pdfView = findViewById(R.id.pdfView1);
        int progress = 1;
        int currentPage = 0;
        scrollSpeed = 0;
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final int delay = 50; //مستوى السرعة تنتهي بهذا الرقم وكلما زاد الرقم قلت السرعة النهائية
        final int maxProgress = seekBar.getMax();
        final int totalPages = pdfView.getPageCount();

        seekBar.setProgress(progress);

        
        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                pdfView.scrollBy(0, scrollSpeed);
                handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
                
            }
        };
        
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, delay);
        
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
  
                scrollSpeed = progress;
            }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }
        });
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, delay);
```

I got very tired trying that, this method works in webview but in PDFview it doesn't work, I asked the artificial intelligence in every way and I didn't get any result and solution